# Azure Container Instance - Access from external is logged with internal IP?

Tags: sftp, azure

I've set up an Azure Container Instance (Ubuntu) with an SFTP-Server. Everything works fine, I can connect from external to my SFTP Server....so as I said everything is ok.

Now I activated rsyslog to log the SSH/SFTP Logins to auth.log...ok this works also! But now, when I connect from external to this Container Instance/SFTP-Server I see in auth.log the following:

Accepted password for root from 10.240.255.56 port 34930 ssh2 Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for root from 10.240.255.56 port 34930 id 0

As you can see there is an login from 10.240.255.56 which is an internal (Azure)IP?! Why is my own external IP not logged?

Comment: How do you connect to the VM/container? Using VPN? Using a load balancer? Using any kind of reverse proxy/security gateway?

Comment: No, I've just created an Azure Container Instance with Public IP and open Port. Then I connect via WinSCP...I've not configured any VNET or LoadBalancer in Azure.